# Are there any studies on changes in British English to become more like American English?

Tags: american-english, british-english, north-american-english, transatlantic-differences, insular-english

With the spread of American popular culture (movies, books, franchises, etc.) and technical jargon (manuals, Web syntaxes, default spell-check settings, etc.), I'm wondering if there have been any studies on a resulting general change in the use of traditional British English conventions, particularly in places such as Britain and Ireland, in the direction of American conventions.

In particular, I'm looking for the results of systematic studies on the topic, or strong evidence for change or lack of change of British English usage.  (For example, the change of a few key conventions over the past 5, 10 or 20 years.)

I refer equally to spoken conventions (e.g., "come and see" vs. "come see") as well as spelling (e.g., "centred" vs. "centered").

Comment: Well, the second derivative is still negative, anyway. But that's just entropy.

Comment: Web syntaxes seems an odd thing to list; when you consider [Sir Berners-Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee) country of origin.

Comment: Regarding Web syntax, for example, it's `center` in HTML, CSS, etc., as well as in various lightweight "user-friendly" syntaxes like Markdown, BBcode, Wiki-markup, etc. Spelling in computer languages is typically American English for whatever reason (it's good that it's consistent).

Comment: @badroit I think you could make a strong argument that there is a trend away from the "[Latinization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latinization_%28historical%29)" that [Noah Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/info/spelling-reform.htm) did not care for.

Comment: There are constant complaints in the press and in parliament that literacy of UK children is in decline. Perhaps this is the cause of it!

Comment: Another factor is the default installation option of many software spell-check features.

Comment: It's a day ending in *y*, so it must be time to [carp about foreign influence on the language](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/10/11/fashion/americans-are-barmy-over-britishisms.html). Half of the time, it is a lazy journalist complaining about a native usage that has simply fallen out of use; otherwise it is a complaint about some neologism that is equally reviled in Cambridge, Mass. and Cambridge, Cambs.

Comment: Hmm. I have no idea why this question has been put on hold as primarily opinion-based. I'm not asking if people *think* British English is in decline. In the second sentence of the question, I specifically asked for details from a study on the topic or other supporting evidence (even if anecdotal).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the *best* it's likely to get here is evidence of a BrE -> AmE shift on a few (probably, *atypical, non-representative*) usages - which my mind, would just be POB. What's being asked for requires a relatively extensive analysis covering a wide range of BrE characteristics from the perspective of [language-change](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/language-change/info) over at linguistics.SE, so that's where I think this question belongs.

Comment: 'Decline'? That implies a tendentious negative direction. What is the (unbiased) direction that you are hypothesizing? Towards Jafaican? Towards uneducated Basic World English? Or do you have some other description of the direction? Oh. I see. American.

Comment: **FumbleFingers**, I think that examples of shifts are perfectly valid answers. The voting system can decide which examples are atypical/non-representative or not. You're probably correct though that this is would be a better question for linguistics.SE. **Mitch**, honestly I'm not sure what your point is. I think my question and its motivation is pretty clear. Moreover, a hypothesis -- as a speculation that needs to confirmed/denied -- does not need to be neutral. My hypothesis is that British English conventions are in decline.

Comment: @ badriot: imho, "British English conventions" are a subset of "minority dialects" in general. And as [this answer on *Linguistics*](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1447/282) says, few published/accredited works currently address even the *general* case, because there are so many variables. And on that question, the specifics of "Internet-driven" change are classified "too early to tell". In your case I'm not sure how you'd distinguish instances of "indigenous and natural internally-driven shifts" from what I imagine you're really bothered about (US "linguistic imperialism").

Comment: If questions about trends in dialect use belong at Linguistics and practical questions about grammar and syntax are "off-topic," it's hard to imagine what kind of questions might be allowed here anymore. Perhaps we should just write-protect the question-submission form, congratulate ourselves on a job well done, and call it a day.

Comment: This question needs to be narrowed down. Choose examples that users could discuss on; *aluminium* and *aluminum* for example, different spellings, pronunciations and in AmEng maybe even different interpretations (I'm not sure on the latter, I'm hypothesizing). Or take how questions are being formed with the auxiliary "do" when talking about possession i.e., *Do you have a dog?* vs. *Have you got a dog?* and "I got myself/meself a dog" vs. "I bought/got a dog for myself". The question is interesting, I'd love to see an authoritative answer, but I don't think you'll get one.

Comment: If you count *"traditional British English"* as the language spoken in 1800 (when US and UK English were much closer together), it's certainly on the decline. The language is constantly changing, and some of these changes are more advanced in the US, while others (e.g., the loss of the subjunctive) are more advanced in the UK. But is it that the US is "corrupting" British English, or is the language just "corrupting itself" the way all languages do?

Comment: @phenry don't you think this question, although hugely interesting, is too vast, too vague and at the same time impossible to answer in a Q&A format? How would one measure the changes that have occurred in the English language in the last five, ten or twenty years?I'm sure native speakers were bemoaning about the fall of standards fifty years ago, and that was only in the 60s!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - The questioner has specifically asked for research studies on the topic, which narrows the scope of the question quite a bit. It may be that no such studies exist, in which case the questioner may never receive a satisfactory answer, but the question as asked is not overbroad.

Comment: @phenry so he's not asking for anybody's opinion, or explanations, only if a research paper has been conducted?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I don't interpret this question as asking for opinions. The questioner is asking for research results or for "strong evidence for a decline/lack of decline," which might be supplied through a mechanism such as Google Ngrams (though I recognize that you are [skeptical](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/how-accurate-is-google-ngram-as-a-language-reference-source) of Ngrams as a tool for assessing BrEng/AmEng differences). I consider "opinion-based" questions to be those that boil down to "What's better?" or the like, and this one doesn't fall into that category.

Answer (score 2):

The flow of expressions between British and American English doesn't just go one way, although I expect today that the predominant direction is from the US to the UK. There is an English professor who [has a blog](http://britishisms.wordpress.com) where he talks about Britishisms entering American English.

Comment: There is a similar (and more wonderfully named blog) [here on such influences](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that as English is always in flux as a living language that British English conventions are not in decline but changing as they have naturally done for hundreds of years.

So the notion of a convention within English is the problem as there is none as such. One can't have a true convention in communication within a living language.

The reason that Grammar was dropped from the English Curriculum was because although English grammar is strongly based upon Latin, there were nothing but problems as Latin was a non-evolving language it had fixed conventions which could be followed nicely; unfortunately it could only be followed nicely by the latin language - English moved on and left the conventions of Latin behind. But Latin was never an appropriate basis for English grammar in the first place so was no great loss.

So, the answer is no, Conventions within the English language are not in decline, they are merely evolving; if they exist at all.

Comment: OP was clearly asking about distinctly British conventions being replaced by American ones.  You may want to try again.

Comment: @DougM And it was answered clearly - English (which American is part of) does NOT have declining conventions - never has never will - they are in flux.

Try again yourself.

Comment: OP is using *decline* in the sense of a decreased frequency of use.

Comment: @user61979 Of course he is - and I stated it is NOT IN DECLINE!
Stop voting me down for NO REASON

Comment: For the Down voters Justify your down votes : Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

So you're interested in both the colloquial and the standard... one is enshrined and gradually changing, the other is not quantifiable, at least so far as I've been led to understand. This site is an excellent example of the modalities and descriptive/prescriptive conversations concerning both. You should check it out some time [sic????] damn i also dont know where to put the period, better just put an ellipsis after "some time". Wait, that's a British formulation. Where you say? There, behind me, the period outside of the quotation marks. Well is it allowed if I'm American? Oh... no... it's actually grammatically correct. Never mind.